# Modify MS 365 unified group membership using PowerShell with Enterprise app authentication

Tags: powershell, office365api

Im trying to run the following command:

```
Add-UnifiedGroupLinks -Identity 'groupemail@domain.com' -LinkType members -Links kavehtest114@gelion.com
```

However, the error I am getting is:

```
Write-ErrorMessage : |Microsoft.Exchange.Net.AAD.AADException|We failed to update the group mailbox. Please try again later.
```

Context is I have authenticated using a certificate connected to an Enterprise app I have registered. If I authenticate as the global admin of the tenant via the standard interactive login, the cmdlet works fine, but I need it to work with the enterprise app for unattended scripts.

The permissions the enterprise app has are:
[image: API permissions]

I've come across this aricle:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/app-only-auth-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps

which says; "In Exchange Online PowerShell, you can't use the procedures in this article with the following Microsoft 365 Group cmdlets: ...Add-UnifiedGroupLinks"

If thats the case, whats the alternative via PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it:

To add a member:

```
New-MgGroupMember -GroupId $GroupID -DirectoryObjectId $UserID
```

To remove a member:

```
Remove-MgGroupMemberByRef -DirectoryObjectId $UserID -GroupId $GroupId
```

`$UserID` is the `id` attribute thats returned from `Get-MgUser` and `$GroupID` is the `Guid` attribute returned from `Get-MgGroup`.